# Sorting Friends based on degree of friend on facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

I have made an app where after a search criteria, the user will get result where all his friends & friends of friends sorted out based on degree of connection.

For example, A is a friend of B. C is a friend of B but not friend of A. D is a friend of C but not A or B

A->B->C->D (Relation between facebook friends)

Now after A puts up the search criteria, the result will be published in following order

B
C
D

So can any of you help me in getting the results sorted out based on degree of contact. If user only wants to see particular degree of friends, there will be a check box, to pick either 1st, or 2nd or 1st & 2nd degree friends

Also do let me know a way, where it wont take too much time in running the query and publishing the search results

Comment: (The real question is how you got access to friends of friends when it is explicitly disallowed by the API)

Comment: no...i am just sorting those friends who have registered into my app.. thus if I have 500 friends and only 100 are on my app, then my search result will sort those 100 based on degree of friendship

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Graph API doesn't allow you to inspect friends of friends.

You can check whether your friend A knows your friend B.

`SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ' + uid1 + ' AND uid2 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

`uid1` would be a friend you supply to check against all your friends.

There is an example of this implemented as a graph at http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/graph.html

Here is a graph of 100 of my friends

[image: Graph]

Comment: How do you sort by who-knows-who though? IE like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8HBNgl3M788/TjgxIYjXc1I/AAAAAAAAIO0/kTvaWpyGaDQ/s1600/Friend%2BWheel%2Bexample.png

Comment: @MattHumphrey you just change the data representation. The data for all the connections is already in `links.push({ "source" : a, "target" : b , "value" : "1" });` under the `pushFriends` function